# Firebase database integration not working from within PhoneGap Build Web app

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, phonegap

I have written a small Web app that interacts with Firebase database.
When I test the app on the browser, everything works fine and any new data that I add to the database, gets reflected automatically on the Firebase database console for my app.

However, when I package my Web app using PhoneGap Build, something is not working properly.
All my calls to the Firebase database seem to be working fine and I even get unique push ids in my app, however nothing gets reflected on the Firebase database console.

Could it be that everything that I do within my PhoneGap Build app with regards to the interaction with the Firebase database is actually done locally and nothing gets transmitted back to the Firebase online database?

Is this a known issue?

I am not using the [Cordova Firebase plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase). Should I be using it? Will it solve the problem? I understand that this plugin does not work well with PhoneGap Build.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
Turns out it is a phonegap issue which is solved when adding the following to the config.xml file:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

I hope this helps anyone

Comment: This was extremely helpful for what I was doing